# Sorting web workers into an array (for later use)

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Objective: make a reusable array of web workers to access each one based on its position in the array for example workers [1] will access the first core built 2 will the second and so on. This is to post messages to them when needed (not only upon creation).

The code Below does not work(due to worker being undefined at postmessage in second for loop)  If possible , would like someone to give a fix if they can or a reason why it's not possible and explain the difference between this and thread.js thread pooling.

Thanks guys,  it can be put more simple than this if you want , just show a way to array a bunch of workers based on the order they were created in .

```
 let workers=[]
 workersWork();
 function workersWork() {

    let coreAmount  =window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency;





    for(let i = 0;i<coreAmount ;i++){

        workers.push(new Worker("./testChildWorker.js"))

    }

 if(workers.length === coreAmount){
    for (let i = 0; i< coreAmount;i++){
        let worker = workers[i]
        let message     ={Procedure:"start",coreCount:i,version:dbVersion};
        worker.postMessage(message);
        worker.onmessage =  messageFunction

     }
    }};




    function messageFunction(event) {
    let worker= workers[event.data.coreCount]
    worker.postmessage("hello")
    let message = event.data;
    alert(message.object.id);

    }
```

Comment: Please review your code, it contains basic syntax (there's at least one unbalanced parenthesis) and logic (indexing an array should start at one) errors. Simplify it, don't try to cope all at once. And return here if still confused with a good description of your problem (*does not work* isn't enough).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism , the index starts at 1 to simplify the way they will be accessed so that I can use the main thread as a middle man for certain things . I stated above that I would probably have some errors of sorts , I am sorry for the inconveniences. I did not want to be coy at all I sort of supplied the code to make people understand what I am after because in other threads they have mistook my questions due to lack of code or clear expression of my objective. The code I have does not work because it says the worker is undefined at the time of the first post message.

Comment: Still don’t understand why you need to use an index of 1. You’re just making this unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I will do my best to correct my code to everyone's liking . If you have a problem , I will fix it(assuming I understand) . Please do know , I do not post my questions if I have not tried my hardest to understand the problem . Trust me I hate asking questions on here , its hard for me (6 months into programming exp) to understand the full of it and if I did I wouldn't be here .

Comment: @PA. Still issues